# Glassfish EJB Remote Interface Multithreaded Application

Tags: glassfish, ejb

I have a multithreaded Java SWT application that connects to a remote stateless bean for some data processing. I am running Glassfish 3.1.1 (build 12) on a Windows 7 32-bit OS under jdk 1.7.0_02.

For each thread accessing the EJB I create a new remote interface object, for example for 2 threads executing in parallel I have,

```
Thread-1
LoginBeanRemote ejbClient = (LoginBeanRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("LoginBean");
ejbClient.doSomething();

Thread-2
LoginBeanRemote ejbClient = (LoginBeanRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("LoginBean");
ejbClient.doSomethingDifferent();
```

Now it runs fine half of the time and gives a 'NullPointerException' on the second line for the rest of the time.

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mypackage.myclass.getListofOperators(LoginBean.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
    at $Proxy180.getListofOperators(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:144)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:174)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

SEVERE:     at com.mypackage.myclass.getListofOperators(LoginBean.java:270)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
SEVERE:     at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
SEVERE:     at $Proxy180.getListofOperators(Unknown Source)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
SEVERE:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:144)

SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:174)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
```

Also the exception not always comes from the same thread, it can be either ejbClient.doSomething() or ejbClient.doSomethingDifferent()

I am not using injection for entitymanager as I need to provide different username and passwords for different sessions and do it as

```
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", loginName);
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:ORCL");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xadp", properties);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(properties);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of the code I can only guess, but it is likely you are using instance variables in your session bean.

The thing about session beans is that, even with a Stateless session bean, the container (in this case Glassfish) can pool the beans.  That means it has many instances of a session bean to service requests and shares them among the clients.

The key point is that a session bean can be given to another client at any time, so if you save state in the bean in an instance or static field, you might have client A make a call and then get interrupted halfway, so client B sees client A's data.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for your response you are probably right as I am not injecting the entitymanager rather building it from the EntityManagerFactory using properties, so probably that object is being shared among beans. Now I have to do it because for different users the bean receives different username and password for underlying database connection. I don't think I can provide different username/password for a datasource and use injection at the same time? right? So in this instance if I can't use injection what should I do?

Comment: What variable is giving the NullPointerException on line 270?    Also, I'm not there in your company's head, but the use case that different users have different user names in the database seems fishy.  Typically you'll do authentication some other way such as LDAP, then have all users connect to the database with a single username/password on the server.  With that setup, you control [access](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/servsecr002.htm) using the @RolesAllowed annotation as a start.

Comment: Another thought, since you are not injecting the EntityManager, you'll probably have to do some work to make sure it joins the right transaction.  Something like [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=978162)

Comment: Thanks again Jim for your time. The application is multiuser AND multithreaded so a user can have multiple threads but each user will only have one u/p and the initial problem was that the application worked fine in single thread but as soon as two threads occurred simultaneously one of them gave a NPE. The exception is completely pasted above from the server logs and it happens on the line where I try to call a method on the remote interface. The reason for having entitymanager created based on username/password is that the user based access management is done by the underlying Oracle DB.

Comment: I can use @RolesAllowed annotation but then I assume I will have to do the user management myself. I will explore the options proposed by you and will give feedback. Thanks again for all the help.